# I have a list of ID's and I need to find which of the ID's are missing from a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, excel

I have an excel list of ID numbers and I need to find which of the numbers listed do not exist as primary keys in a certain table.

I tried doing something like

```
="Select * from table where `exchangeID` =" &A1&";"
```

in Excel, in order to generate select statements for every row. I thought by running a select on an ID that didn't exist would return an error. There's several hundred ID's, however, and copying and pasting the huge list of selects didn't do much aside from return the results of the last couple.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert the list into a table (can be a temp table) then join against your table with a LEFT JOIN.

Something like this:-

```
CREATE TABLE temp
(
ID_NUMBER INT
);

INSERT INTO temp VALUES (1), (2), (3)
```

Then the JOIN

```
SELECT a.ID_NUMBER
FROM temp a
LEFT OUTER JOIN sometable b
ON a.ID_NUMBER = b.exchangeID
WHERE b.exchangeID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, my first answer got the question the wrong way around, re-reading it.

**To find all IDs in the database that are not in the Excel:**

Get your Excel to generate a column of IDs like this:

```
="'" & A1 & "',"
```

Copy and paste the result column into a text file (Notepad, etc).

Copy this text into your SQL statement:

```
select * from table where not `echangeID` in ([paste your list here]);
```

Don't forget to remove the last , (comma) from the list.

**To find all values in the Excel that aren't in the spreadsheet:**

You will need to insert the values from Excel into another table. You can easily do this with a .csv import.

```
select id from [Excel table] where not id in (select id from [original table]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear how Excel fits in with your question but something like this might work

```
select * from table where exchangeID not in (34,35,39,101,102)
```

Where 34,35,39,101 and 102 are the list of interesting id numbers